# Direct concurrent Python / PyDev outputs to single Console?

Tags: windows, eclipse, pydev

Python 3.5, PyDev in Eclipse Neon, Windows 7 64-bit.

Is it possible to get concurrent Python 3 programs, preferably run via  Eclipse -> PyDev -> Run, to output to a single output Console? (Not to be confused with Python's *Interactive Console*).

I have two Python programs that (use ZeroMQ to) exchange messages. As shown here, by default each program directs its output to a separate Console tab:

[image]

I'd like the flow of the two programs' sends/receives to be displayed in a single trace-like window. Is there some relatively straightforward way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

### Yes:  <sup>a nice task with ZeroMQ framework</sup>

1. **`import zmq`**
2. create a third programme, a central logging-service, that may run on separate host / server
3. setup a **`SUB`**-type communication archetype behaviour for collecting log-messages
4. expose a known address target-node `.bind( "tcp://<A.B.C.D>:<port>" )` to allow others to **`.connect()`** to
5. allow logging by **`.setsockopt( zmq.SUBSCRIBE, "" )`**
6. start logging by infinite loop with both a **`.poll( ... )`** + **`.recv( zmq.NOBLOCK )`**
7. equip a **`PUB`**-type communication archetype behaviour in each process you need to log
8. make a **`.connect( "tcp://<A.B.C.D>:<port>" )`** to the logger
9. send a logging messages as needed with **`.send( ..., zmq.NOBLOCK )`**

### Tweaking:

- if in trouble with data-flow, may benefit from several separate I/O-threads on the receiver side, launched in the`.Context( nIOthreads )` instantiation step.
- as levels of traffic grow, tweak so called HighWaterMark settings on SUB-side, where concetrated reading/processing/storing gets fastest beyond default hardware limits
- expect issues with slow storage, if in a need to both print on screen + store in a filesystem
- may pre-cache data to collect/assemble data into larger blocks that will thereafter go into fileIO operation, but be carefull with blocking nature of the most of the fileIO sub-systems
- may pre-compress resulting data-to-store so as to gain a slight edge on data-sizes that must go to the fileIO sub-system, but beware, data-"hydraulics" is unforgiving and may be blocking, which we strive to avoid at all in high performance data-flows ).
- may pre-label logging messages with ( w10: `time.monotonic()` ) timestamps to handle artifacts of out of natural order processing on the logger side, in case of heavy dataflow-loads, multiple IO-buffers etc.

Comment: I'm new to ZeroMQ so this will take me a while to assemble. But I definitely appreciate the overview of what I'll need to do to set this up: Learning how to get this working will surely be useful in more than one way.